# Conditional link with Javascript on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create a conditional link based on the width of the window. It's possible there's a better way to do this that I haven't thought of.

There is a horizontal row of square "buttons" with image icons and titles, and when clicking one of the buttons, a small info window drops below the row of "buttons." I used this Javascript for that:

```
jQuery(function($)("#individuals-full a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".toggle").hide();
    var toShow = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery(toShow).show();
});
```

The problem is that, because there are so many buttons, which collapse to a vertical row on mobile view, it is impractical. The reason being that the "info" window is below *all* the buttons here, which creates an issue for the user having to scroll very far, and possibly not being aware that there even is a window below all the buttons.

What I would like to do is create a link for every button, which goes to a separate page (one for each button), if the window width is below a certain amount (let's say 700px), rather than displaying the "info" window below all the buttons.

Here is the HTML for the div with all the buttons, but shortened to just include the code for one of the buttons:

```
    <div id="individuals-full"><h1 style="text-align: center;">We assist    individual clients to find personalized solutions involving:</h1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#fiance-content"><div id="fiance" class="individual-icons"><img  class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-1268"  src="finance-visas-01- 300x300.png" alt="" width="300" height="300"><h1 style="text-align:  center;">Fiancé Visas</h1></div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div id="info-panel">
<div id="fiance-content" class="toggle" style="display:none"><hr/>
<h2>Best If You Want to Avoid a Long Separation</h2>
When the most important thing is for a couple to be together as quickly as  possible, then the fiancé visa usually delivers.  The average processing time (and thus, a good estimate of the period of separation from each other) is 6-8 months, the period from application to admission to the U.S.
</div>
```

Comment: Probably best to just use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) here.

Comment: How would I use media queries to make a link appear?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that it's your `e.preventDefault();` that's stopping the proper click function so just reinstate it when you're on mobile.

Get the width of the window, then within your function add an if statement to check if the window width is bigger than mobile, if it is then run this function. If you're on mobile, it'll get skipped.

```
var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).outerWidth();

jQuery(function($)("#individuals-full a").click(function(e){

    if ( viewportWidth > 768 ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery(".toggle").hide();
        var toShow = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery(toShow).show();

    }

});
```

Comment: I may have been unclear, but it's working on mobile. What I want to do is to take the user to a new page for each item on mobile view, rather than having the info window open like it does on desktop.